# error while calling socket() function

Tags: c

errno is set to error no 40(Too many symbolic links encountered) when socket returns -1.
It would be very helpful to know what will solve this problem.

Comment: Could you provide some more info - Which platform/OS is this on, and also show the code that exhibits this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Are you opening a Unix-domain socket?  If so, specify a name which does not involve a loop of symbolic links, such as:

```
ln -s a b
ln -s b a
```

If you try using either 'a' or 'b', you will get the 'too many symbolic links' error.

Answer (score 0):

That seems quite unusual as socket(3) returns a new file descriptor.  Assuming you are using Linux, then it is not socket that is giving you the error code (socket() will return ENFILE on any file-based error in acquiring the descriptor).

To track this down, I would do two things:  First ensure that errno is cleared before you call socket().  Next store errno in a local variable immediately on exiting socket() with an error.  I think you will find that errno is set to a different value or it is a different function that is failing.